# How to escape question mark '?' in Core Data predicate

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

I'm trying to fetch core data objects using predicate with assets library url:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "url == %@", imageURL)
```

where imageURL is a string like: `assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=6E5438ED-9A8C-4ED0-9DEA-AB2D8F8A9360&ext=JPG`

At run time, I always get an exception. But if I remove the question mark from url string, everything works fine.

Then I found: "The question mark (?) character is not a valid parser token." in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html).

Is there anything I can do if I really need to use the '?' as part of my predicate string?

**UPDATE:**

At first I thought my problem is related to question mark since the app can work if I just remove '?' from imageURL. But then I found it isn't, the predicate can escape '?' automatically in some sample code.

Then I tried to delete the core data store file and everything just works, so I think the problem is caused by inconsistency of the data model

Comment: Try escaping it with `\?`

Comment: Thanks Bluehound, I believe it is the correct way too, but I still haven't figured out how to it yet. If I insert \ before ?, the predicate compiler will just ignore the slash and the same exception will be raised.

Comment: Hmm try two slashes then: \\?  I saw something that showed someone doing that. Not sure if it'll work but worth a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure the object is a string. It should work if the `?` is properly wrapped in a string object.

If it is really a string you can construct the predicate and filter an NSArray without problems. The following works as expected. (For simplicity, I use `self` and a simple array rather than an array of NSManagedObjects with a `url` attribute, but the mechanics are the same.)

```
let url = "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=6E5438ED"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "self = %@", url)!
let array = [ "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=6E5438ED", 
              "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=48765" ] as NSArray
let filtered = array.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)
```

If, however you have a `NSURL` object, you have to make sure you get a proper string representation. Replacing the first line above with:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=6E5438ED")!
```

You need to make sure you pass the correct string to the predicate.

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "self = %@", url.description)!
```

The above also works as expected.

Comment: Thanks Mundi, your sample code works for me too. The problem I met is a bit weird, indeed I passed a string to the predicate. After I deleted the core data store file and start the app again, the issue is gone. I don't know why but thank you anyway for letting me know the predicate can escape question mark automatically.

Comment: Ah, very good. I thought the NSURL might be upsetting it, as the NSPredicate has different rules depending on the type of object substituted into the format string. I guess it doesn't handle other objects exactly as it does strings.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add quotation marks :

```
(format: "url == '%@'", imageURL)
```

Comment: I've tried it, with the quotation mark, the predicate will be (url == "(null)"), thus it will return nothing

Comment: By the way the usage of single quote in not correct in your answer. Please check it through predicate programming guide.

Answer (score -2):

Use the `like` operator rather than `==`.  This will theoretically match all strings with a single character in place of the ?, but I doubt you will get false positives:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "url like %@", imageURL)
```